# Tkinter: right align Labels within stretched LabelFrames using grid

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, grid-layout

Using `grid` in `tkinter`, I'm trying to align a set of frames (I would love to post a picture, but I'm not allowed.)

I've two outer `LabelFrames` of different sizes and on top of each other which I'd like to stretch and align.
Within the bottom frame, I've a stack of several other `LabelFrames` and within each of the `LabelFrames` there is a `Label`. I would like for the `LabelFrames` to extend as much as the outer container and for each of the inner `Labels` to be right align with respect to the containing `LabelFrame`.

I've tried, without success, with various combinations of `sticky`, `anchor`, `justify`.

Any suggestion, recommendation?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk



class AlignTest(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()
        self.parent.title('Align test')
        self.createMenus()
        self.createWidgets()


    def createMenus(self):
        # Menu
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=self.menubar)

        # Menu->File
        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)

        # Menu->Quit
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label='Quit',
                                  command=self.onExit)

        # Create File Menu
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='File',
                                 menu=self.fileMenu)


    def createWidgets(self):

        # Main frame
        self.mainFrame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Outer LabelFrame1
        self.outerLabelFrame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.mainFrame,
                                             text='Outer1')
        self.outerLabelFrame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Inner Label
        self.innerLabel = tk.Label(self.outerLabelFrame1,
                                   text='This is a longer string, for example!')
        self.innerLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)


        # Outer LabelFrame2
        self.outerLabelFrame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.mainFrame,
                                             text='Outer2')
        self.outerLabelFrame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

        # Inner labelFrames each with a single labels
        self.innerLabel1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.outerLabelFrame2,
                                         bg='yellow',
                                         text='Inner1')
        self.innerLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.value1 = tk.Label(self.innerLabel1,
                               bg='green',
                               text='12.8543')
        self.value1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='')

        self.innerLabel2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.outerLabelFrame2,
                                         bg='yellow',
                                         text='Inner2')
        self.innerLabel2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.value2 = tk.Label(self.innerLabel2,
                               bg='green',
                               text='0.3452')
        self.value2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='')

        self.innerLabel3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.outerLabelFrame2,
                                         bg='yellow',
                                         text='Inner3')
        self.innerLabel3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='')
        self.value3 = tk.Label(self.innerLabel3,
                               bg='green',
                               text='123.4302')
        self.value3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='')

    def onExit(self):
        self.parent.quit()



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AlignTest(root)
    app.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even running your code I see two problems. The first is that you aren't always using the `sticky` parameter when calling `grid`. That could be part of the problem. I've rarely ever used `grid` without using that parameter.

The second problem is that you aren't giving any of your rows and columns any weight. Without a positive weight, columns and rows will only ever use up exactly as much space as they need for their contents, and no more. Any extra space goes unallocated.

A good rule of thumb is that in every widget that is being used as a container for other widgets (typically, frames), you should always give at least one row and one column a positive weight.

As a final suggestion: during development it's really helpful to give each of your frames a distinctive color. This really helps to visualize how the frames are using the available space.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! The `weight` was indeed the key to the solution. One interesting note is that the `weight` should be set as property for the widget that *contains* the widget you'd like to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bryan's comment on `weight`, here is a working version of the code as potential reference. (I'll add pictures when allowed.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk



class AlignTest(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()
        self.parent.title('Align test')
        self.createMenus()
        self.createWidgets()


    def createMenus(self):
        # Menu
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=self.menubar)

        # Menu->File
        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)

        # Menu->Quit
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label='Quit',
                                  command=self.onExit)

        # Create File Menu
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='File',
                                 menu=self.fileMenu)


    def createWidgets(self):

        # Main frame
        self.mainFrame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Outer LabelFrame1
        self.outerLabelFrame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.mainFrame,
                                             text='Outer1')
        self.outerLabelFrame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Inner Label
        self.innerLabel = tk.Label(self.outerLabelFrame1,
                                   text='This is a longer string, for example!')
        self.innerLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)


        # Outer LabelFrame2
        self.outerLabelFrame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.mainFrame,
                                             text='Outer2')
        self.outerLabelFrame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.outerLabelFrame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Inner labelFrames each with a single labels
        self.innerLabel1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.outerLabelFrame2,
                                         bg='yellow',
                                         text='Inner1')
        self.innerLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.innerLabel1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.value1 = tk.Label(self.innerLabel1,
                               bg='green',
                               anchor='e',
                               text='12.8543')
        self.value1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')


        self.innerLabel2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.outerLabelFrame2,
                                         bg='yellow',
                                         text='Inner2')
        self.innerLabel2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.innerLabel2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.value2 = tk.Label(self.innerLabel2,
                               bg='green',
                               anchor='e',
                               text='0.3452')
        self.value2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')


        self.innerLabel3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.outerLabelFrame2,
                                         bg='yellow',
                                         text='Inner3')
        self.innerLabel3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.innerLabel3.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.value3 = tk.Label(self.innerLabel3,
                               bg='green',
                               anchor='e',
                               text='123.4302')
        self.value3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')

    def onExit(self):
        self.parent.quit()



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AlignTest(root)
    app.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```